# is it possible to install kakasi without root privileges?

Tags: shell, root

The tool [KAKASI](http://kakasi.namazu.org/)
for converting Japanese text into their equivalent in phonetic alphabets.

I am trying to install with the .rpm or other build guides from the source all install in the `root` dir,

I do not have access to install there since i am on a shared server with Bluehost.

So obviously running the rpm or following those steps would just result in permission errors.

Is there a way to install this tool in say the HTML public directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you download the source code .tar.gz from [here](http://kakasi.namazu.org/) (currently `kakasi-2.3.4.tar.gz`), you can compile from source and install where ever you want.

In the following, I'll use `$KAKASI_DIR` to refer to the directory you want to install it to.

```
?> tar xfvz kakasi-2.3.4.tar.gz
?> cd kakasi-2.3.4
?> configure --prefix $KAKASI_DIR
?> make
?> make install
```

Check after each step if there were any error messages. I just ran the procedure on Fedora 17 without problems, but if you get any errors, it's most likely related to missing dependencies. Unlike `rpm`, building from source means you need to make sure you have all dependencies installed before you start the installation.

Comment: it seems to have worked, I found no errors after doing it your way. but isnt there something i have to put in the php.ini now? and or put a kakasi file in the extentions folder?

Comment: i found the lib libkakasi.so in the public_html/lib/ folder that was made after the make install, so i tried add this line to my php.ini 
extension=/home/mrhowtos/public_html/lib/libkakasi.so

but that doesnt seem to work, the kakasi function call is still considered a call to an undefined function

Comment: I am not sure how to solve this problem; I've never used shared libraries with php. Have you considered asking a separate question about this?